# Pure functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I understand functions need to be pure in order to avoid side-effects. The the following function for example:

```js
//Approach 1
buildValidationErrors(state){

  let validationErrors = [];
  
  if(state.name === null)
  {
    validationErrors.push("Name");
  }
  
  if(state.email === null)
  {
    validationErrors.push("Email");
  }
  
  if(state.mobile === null)
  {
    validationErrors.push("mobile");
  }
  
  return validationErrors;
}

//Approach 2
_buildError(state,itemName,validationErrors){
  if(state[itemName] === null){
     validationErrors.push(itemName);
  }
}

buildValidationErrors1(state){

  let validationErrors = [];
  
 _buildError(state,"Name",validationErrors );
 _buildError(state,"Email",validationErrors);
 _buildError(state,"mobile",validationErrors);
  
  return validationErrors;
}
```

In "Approach 1", you have a long function that builds an array. In "Approach 2" I am extracting the reusable logic to "_buildError" to avoid duplication of logic.

However, in Approach 2, the parameter validationErrors is passed in and it is updated as well causing the function to become 'impure' to my understanding.

From that perspective, can the function be pure and compact?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid passing the errors array by merging the results outside the `_buildError()` function:

```
_buildError(state,itemName){
  return state[itemName] === null ? itemName : null; 
}

buildValidationErrors1(state){

  let validationErrors = [];
  
  validationErrors.push(
     _buildError(state,"Name"),
     _buildError(state,"Email"),
     _buildError(state,"mobile")
  ).filter((a)=> a !== null);


  
  return validationErrors;
}
```

However, that does not really change the purity of the function. In your 2nd example, the function depends and change only its parameters, thus it is "pure" enough for automated tests and other practical purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider

```
_buildError(state,itemName){
   return state[itemName] === null ? itemName : null;
}

// reduce if you need more than one thing in the validation array

let validationErrors = ["Name","Email","mobile"]
  .reduce((acc,item) => {
   if (_buildError(state,item)) acc.push({item,something:state[item].something}); return acc },
  [] );

// filter if you just need the item name

let validationErrors = ["Name","Email","mobile"]
  .filter(item => _buildError(state,item));
```

Comment: That looks like you should use `filter`, not `reduce`+`push`.

Comment: I wrote a filter first, but that only filters the name - I don't know why, but I expected more attributes than the name. Anyway, added both